# Why is it $\frac { n! }{ r! } $ and not $n! - r!$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The number of ways to arrange n objects is $n!$. The number of ways to arrange n objects when r objects are the same is  $\frac { n! }{ r! } $. Why is $n!$ **divided** by $r!$?

Comment: Because it is $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(r+1)$.

Comment: Consider some extreme cases. What if $n=r$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the number of ways that you can arrange $n$ objects when $r$ of them are similar. Thus, we wish to show that $x = \frac{n!}{r!}$. This is equivalent to showing that $n! = x\cdot r!$.

Now consider $n$ objects with $r$ of them being similar and first consider the number of ways we can arrange them if we pretend the $r$ objects are distinguishable. Clearly, this can be done in $n!$ ways.

Alternatively, we could first count the number of ways to arrange the objects in which the $r$ objects are indistinguishable. There are $x$ ways to do this. Then for each one of those ways, we could then rearrange the $r$ objects in $r!$ ways. It should be clear that this process will generate every possible ordering of the $n$ objects (assuming distinguishability) exactly once. By the multiplication principle, there are $x\cdot r!$ ways to order the $n$ objects pretending that the $r$ objects are distinguishable.

Notice that $n!$ and $x \cdot r!$ refer to the number of ways to count the same thing, and thus, $n! = x\cdot r! \implies x = \frac{n!}{r!}$.

Answer (score 1):

In both of these cases, we start with a set which we can easily count, and "correct" the number in some way.

We use subtraction when we have a subset we want to exclude, and division when we partition the set into equivalence classes of the same size.  For example:

- *Subtraction*: E.g. There are $n!-r!$ ways to arrange $n$ objects, excluding those which begin with $\{1,\ldots,r\}$ in some order followed by $r+1,\ldots,n$ in order.
- *Division*: In the given problem, we're considering the number of ways to arrange $n$ objects when $r$ objects are the same.  We can think of the $n$ objects as $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and the $r$ objects as $\{1,\ldots,r\}$ which we consider as identical.  We consider two arrangements of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ equivalent if they differ only up to the positions of elements in $\{1,\ldots,r\}$.  In this way, everything belongs to equivalence classes of size $r!$, so there are $n!/r!$ equivalence classes.